# Condition the selection with respect to 2 columns to return max value in one column for duplicate entries in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE COL1 IN (1, 2, 3) AND COL2 IN (7, 8, 9)
```

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 ​ | 7 |
| 2 ​ | 8 |
| 2 ​ | 9 |
| 3 ​ | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |

I want the result to be the maximum entry in COL2 for each of the COL1 entries, as below.

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 ​ | 9 |
| 3 | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that just

```
select col1, Max(col2)
from table
where col1 in (1, 2, 3) and col2 in (7, 8, 9)
group by col1
```